# Running webdriverio in docker (codeship)

Tags: selenium, docker, webdriver-io, codeship

I am currently trying to setup a basic repo for my next [React project](https://github.com/MaxKalb/reap). 
For that I want to have end-to-end tests in place via webdriverio + cucumber.

While just running `wdio` works fine locally, I cannot get it to run in my docker container. Even though I added [wdio-docker-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wdio-docker-service) it told me:

```
(service: reap) (step: feature_tests) A service failed in the
'onPrepare' hook (service: reap) (step: feature_tests) Error: not
found: java
```

When I was installing java manually in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/MaxKalb/reap/blob/master/Dockerfile) it would complain:

```
(service: reap) (step: feature_tests) A service failed in the
'onPrepare' hook (service: reap) (step: feature_tests) Error: Selenium
server did not start. (service: reap) (step: feature_tests) Another
Selenium process may already be running or your java version may be
out of date. (service: reap) (step: feature_tests) Be sure to check
the official Selenium release notes for minimum required java version:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error seems to be coming from the 'selenium-standalone' service you're loading, which tries to start Selenium via Java. Since you're using the 'node' docker image, it doesn't have Java installed.

To use the 'wdio-docker-service', you need to get replace 'selenium-standalone' with 'docker' in [your services line](https://github.com/MaxKalb/reap/blob/master/wdio.conf.js#L113).

There will be two docker images running, the one with your tests that WebdriverIO is run on (Node), and the one running selenium standalone (started by wdio-docker-service).

Alternatively, you can run your WebdriverIO command locally, and just use Docker for the selenium standalone instance. That's probably easier, but less portable.